# Group_Concat with join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, union, group-concat

I have these two tables **t_main**

| Ticket | Date | Main_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23/11/2020 | AA |
| 1 | 23/11/2020 | BB |
| 2 | 10/11/2020 | BB |
| 3 | 13/11/2020 | AA |
| 3 | 13/11/2020 | CC |
| 3 | 13/11/2020 | BB |
| 4 | 13/11/2020 | AA |

and **t_task**:

| Ticket | Task_Number | Task_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | BB |
| 1 | 3 | CC |
| 3 | 1 | AA |
| 3 | 2 | CC |
| 3 | 2 | AA |
| 3 | 1 | BB |
| 4 | 1 | AA |
| 4 | 2 | AA |
| 4 | 2 | CC |

So far I've achieved to `group_concat` the status for the `t_main` and `t_task` separately.

This is the desired output:

| Ticket | Date | Main_Status_Concat | Task_Number | Task_Status_Concat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23/11/2020 | AA BB | 3 | BB CC |
| 2 | 10/11/2020 | BB | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| 3 | 13/11/2020 | AA CC BB | 1 | AA BB |
| 3 | 13/11/2020 | AA CC BB | 2 | CC AA |
| 4 | 13/11/2020 | AA | 1 | AA |
| 4 | 13/11/2020 | AA | 2 | AA CC |

I can execute the queries separately, I cannot join them

Query #1: returning all concatenated status for tickets

```
SELECT 
    t_main.ticket,
    Group_Concat(MAIN_STATUS Separator ' ' ) AS Main_Status_Concat 
FROM t_main t1
GROUP BY t1.ticket;
```

Query #2: returning tickets with task and concat task_status

```
SELECT  
    t_task.ticket, t_task.task_number,
    Group_Concat(TASK_STATUS Separator ' ' ) AS Task_Status_Concat FROM 
    t_task t2
GROUP BY
    t2.ticket, t2.task;
```

I can join having the task ID with the t_main columns, but cannot get to show the concat tasks status properly.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Join the main table with the subquery that gets the tasks.

```
SELECT m.ticket, m.date, GROUP_CONCAT(m.main_status SEPARATOR ' ') AS main_status_concat, t.task_number, t.task_status_concat
FROM t_main AS m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ticket, task_number,
        Group_Concat(TASK_STATUS Separator ' ') AS Task_Status_Concat 
    FROM t_task
    group by ticket, task_number
) AS t ON m.ticket = t.ticket
GROUP BY m.ticket, t.task_number, m.date, t.task_status_concat
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vC6FXDdmuBDZC4iEwzh3RH/0)

Comment: I tried it and it does not show multiple tasks and it´s concat_Status :(

I´m trying with a Cross Join, I´m having issues displaying correctly the ticket stat_concat

Comment: Sorry, needed to include `task_number` in the grouping at the end.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, had to ad the t.item column & grouping also to be able to see all the task associated to each ticket

This works now